# could anyone tell me the difference between the first code and the second one?

Tags: c++, recursion

Could anyone tell me the difference between the first code and the second  one?

The first works on  (https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/189/A) cut ribbon problem while the other doesn't work.

1-

```
ll s(ll nn)
{

    if (nn < 0)
        return -1e9;

    else if (nn == 0)
        return 0;

    t= max({ s(nn - a) + 1, s(nn - b) + 1, s(nn - c) + 1 });
    return t;

}
```

2-

```
ll t = -1e9;

ll s(ll nn)
{

    if (nn < 0)
        return -1e9;

    else if (nn == 0)
        return 0;

    t = max(s(nn - a) + 1, t);
    t = max(s(nn - b) + 1, t);
    t = max(s(nn - c) + 1, t);

    return t;

}
```

Comment: How far in your analysis did you come yourself?

Comment: In the first code `s` is a pure function. In the second code the return value depends on `t`.

Comment: @pjs the second code does have this line added at the top: `ll t = -1e9;`.

Comment: @pjs No. It looks to me like the definition (+ initialization) of a global variable. But, on further thought, it **is** wrong (as pointed out in the given answer). It will only be initialized **once** - at compile time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that while function `s` computes `max(...)` in the first snippet, the second version  computes `max(..., t)`.

Why not declare `t` as a local variable?